# Collection DropdownList loses its value on rending the view - Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, collections, dropdownlistfor

On my Asp.net MVC form (.cshtml),
**Scenario** : When the user clicks the button to modify the already saved form as a draft copy, the httpGet method is called that is supposed to rendre the form view with all the previously saved fields but only the Colletions's drop-down lists are failing to do so and losing their values while rendering, even though their values are correctly recieved via the ViewModel.

Only this collection of operations in which the drop-down lists are losing their values they have recieved while rendering the view.
I've other normal dropdownlists in the same form that are directly declared in the model and they're displaying correctly their values.

Example of my ViewModel :

```
//SaveNFDemandeExpressionViewModel.cs file
 
public class SaveNFDemandeExpressionViewModel : NFDemandeBaseVIewModel
{
    //Other Field values

    //List of Operations
    public List<PartialViewModels.NFOperationViewModel> ListeOperations { get; set; }

    //Other Field values
}

//NFOperationViewModel.cs file

//What my Operation ViewModel looks like :
public class NFOperationViewModel
{
    public string NotificationNum { get; set; }
    public int OperationEtapeNum { get; set; }
    public int OperationPhaseID { get; set; }
    public string OperationPhaseNom { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> OperationEtapeAIPList { get; set; }
    public bool OperationEtapeAIPID { get; set; }
    public string OperationEtapeAIPNom { get; set; }
    public int OperationNotificationTypeID { get; set; }
    public string OperationNotificationTypeNom { get; set; }
    public string OperationDesignation { get; set; }        
}
```

Here's the example of the display of the Collection List in my form view:

```
//EditConfirmation.cshtml

@if (Model.ListeOperations != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListeOperations.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>                                                        
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationEtapeNum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = Model.ListeOperations[i].OperationEtapeNum } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationEtapeNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>                
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationDesignation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = Model.ListeOperations[i].OperationDesignation } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationDesignation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationEtapeAIPID, new SelectList(Model.ListeOperations[i].OperationEtapeAIPList, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = Model.ListeOperations[i].OperationEtapeAIPID })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationNotificationTypeNom, ViewBag.ListesTypesNotifications as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationNotificationTypeNom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationPhaseID, ViewBag.ListesPhases as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ListeOperations[i].OperationPhaseID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn AddNewOperation" value="Add"><span class="material-icons md--blue-corporate size-3P">add_circle</span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

For example, I have the exact same type of dropdown list on the same form that works pretty fine

```
//Other drop-down list in the same view which is not in a list collection and that renders correctly

<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjetCode, ViewBag.ListesProjets as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjetCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</td>
```

Just in case, the httpGet method that sends us back the form in modification mode

```
//controller with the httpGet method

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit_Expression(string id)
        {
            // Récupération de la notiifcation
            NF_TA_NOTIFICATION_NFO tmpNotif = this.demandeService.Find(id);
            
            // On récupère la demande
            ConfirmNFDemandeExpressionViewModel ViewModelNotif = this.demandeService.ConvertIntoConfirmExpressionViewModel(tmpNotif);

            // On gère les listes déroulantes
            GererListesExpression();

            // Ajout du titre et du mode
            ViewBag.titre = String.Format(Resources.Commun.Demande_Titre_Notification_Modification, id);
            ViewBag.mode = Models.Common.Constants.VIEW_MODE_MODIFICATION;

            return View("EditConfirmation", ViewModelNotif);
        }
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've changed the list from dropdownlist to dropdown list for
- converted the list into strongly typed
- tried to see if I can use other proposed methods with page_load and stuff(i don't have a page-load method in my application)

Comment: What are you talking about? What is a postback and what is get? MVC are not webforms and don't have any postback.  Can you post your get action and get view with dropdown list, and post action where are trying to catch ddl values? We don't need any another information.

Comment: @Serge Your comment made my realized that my explaination was a bit wrong than what i wanted to say. So I have edited my question. please have a look. thanks!

PS: it's only towards the rendering of the view that the Drop-down lists of the collection are failing to load the values!